# Cannot get Pylons to work with mongokit

Tags: python, mongodb, pylons, mongokit

I've tried following the guide for intergrating mongokit into pylons thats here: http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/pylons.html

When I go to serve with paster it throws the error:

```
File "/home/ciferkey/Projects/runnr-site/runnrsite/config/environment.py", line 29, in load_environment
config['pylons.app_globals'] = app_globals.Globals(config)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

if I throw a dummy parameter into the **init** for Globals:

```
def __init__(self, foo):
```

then it no longer throw the error but instead throws:

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pylons/configuration.py", line 141, in __getitem__
return dict.__getitem__(self, name)
KeyError: 'db_host'
```

Now this is referencing the lines in lib/app_globals.py that the guide tells you to put in:

```
self.connection = Connection(
      host = config['db_host'],
      port = int(config['db_port']),
    )
```

and i understand that I'm to replace db_host and db_port with the actual information, but no matter what I try it throws the same error. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Replace config['db_host'] with "127.0.0.1" and config['db_port'] with 27017 or add both values to your Pylons config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Mongoengine? I'm currently using it for my own Pylons project and found it very easy to setup and use. http://www.cleverkoala.com/2010/09/how-to-integrate-mongoengine-into-pylons/

Comment: I have but unfortunately I have another piece of software that creates the data in mongodb which I am having the site display and that already uses mongokit. However I was able to get monogkit working with Christian Joudrey's tip and some finessing of my own.